# Parts of the texture are showing as semitranslucent in render mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, transparency

I was wondering if I could get some help with a problem I've been recently having, when I try to create a Image Render of some grass for a course that I've been working on, it ends up looking like this:

[image]

For some reason, parts of the grass texture are missing & I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening.

When the grass is displayed in Rendered Mode, there seems to be a similar problem where parts of the grass appear to be semi-translucent for some unknown reason.  However, when the grass is displayed in Material Mode, the grass appears to be fine.

Any help with dealing with this problem would be appreciated.

Edit 1:

I've added a screenshot that includes the Node Editor and the Material Settings.  I hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: You will have to provide more info if you want any useful answers. Please edit your question and provide more details like material settings, node setup, screenshots, and possible a **simplified** [blend file with minimal data to reproduce the problem](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and packed textures

Comment: Did you UV map the textures properly? Perhaps the UV's align with a transparent section of the texture instead of the grass blades?

Comment: Without looking at the node tree there is no way to guess what you are doing.